# Trying to get user input to work correctly

Tags: java, recursion, user-input, towers-of-hanoi

I have a towers of hanoi puzzle program that is getting closer to being done. My problem right now is trying to get my input from the user to work properly.

If they type 'v' or 'V', then the steps to solve the puzzle will be displayed (Hence the output would be 'Move Disc from S to D' and so forth) . Else, if the user does not type 'v' or 'V', then the program proceeds with in solving the puzzle, displaying the Total moves but not displaying the steps.

The problem I am having is the options aren't working like they are supposed to.

**Now the only thing wrong is when the user input's 'v' or 'V', the moves are not displayed correctly. 
Output:**

```
Enter the min number of discs : 
2
Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves
v
 Move disc from needle S to A
 Total Moves : 3
```

**How can I accomplish having the moves displayed if the user types 'v' or 'V', and if the user types some other than this the output just displays the 'Total Moves'?**

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowerOfHanoi4 {
   static int moves=0;
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   System.out.println("Enter the min number of discs : ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int iHtMn = scanner.nextInt();       //iHeightMin         

        char source='S', auxiliary='D', destination='A';       //name poles or 'Needles'

   System.out.println("Press 'v' or 'V' for a list of moves");     
        Scanner show = new Scanner(System.in);
        String c = show.next();
        // char lstep='v', lsteps='V';       // grab option v or V

   if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("v")){        //if option is not v or V, execute code and only display total moves
    hanoi(iHtMn, source, destination, auxiliary); //else, user typed v or V and moves are displayed
    System.out.println(" Move disc from needle "+source+" to "+destination);
    System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
   } else {
      hanoi(iHtMn, source, destination, auxiliary);
      System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
     }  
   }


    static void hanoi(int htmn,char  source,char  destination,char  auxiliary)
      {
      if (htmn >=1)
          {
             hanoi(htmn-1, source, auxiliary, destination); // move n-1 disks from source to auxilary
              // System.out.println(" Move disc from needle "+source+" to "+destination); // move nth disk to destination
             moves++;     
             hanoi(htmn-1, auxiliary, destination, source);//move n-1 disks from auxiliary to Destination
          }
          // else (
      }
}
```

Comment: why do you have multiple scanners?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is in the `else if` condition, when ever you type `v` or `V`, the application goes for the first if and condition get true, so your `else if` is never executed.

One `if` condition is enough, try it like this

```
//if option is not v or V, execute code and only display total moves
//else, user typed v or V and moves are displayed
if (c == lstep || c == lsteps){
    hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary); 
    System.out.println(" Move disc from needle "+source+" to "+destination);
    System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
} else {
    hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
    System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
}
```

And by the way, you don't need multiple scanners in your code, only one is enough.

Also no need to define two `char` to compare against them, you could easily do it like this:

```
String c = show.next();

//if option is not v or V, execute code and only display total moves
//else, user typed v or V and moves are displayed
if (c.equalsIgnoreCase("v")){
    hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
    System.out.println(" Move disc from needle "+source+" to "+destination);
    System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
} else {
    hanoi(iHeight, source, destination, auxiliary);
    System.out.println(" Total Moves : "+moves);
}
```

**UPDATE** according to your last edit, you could define a static `boolean` field and move your if condition to your `hanoi` method

Check the pastebin [here](http://pastebin.com/efEKjRNJ)

Comment: Thank you so much. It's almost working except now when I type v or V, the output is incorrect. I edited my code above to show you. How do I get it to display the move list correctly?

Comment: Just move this print statement `System.out.println(" Move disc from needle "+source+" to "+destination);` inside your `hanoi` method, and move the if condition for this statement only to it, you could add one more `boolean` parameter to your method or define a static boolean field

Comment: When I move the if condition to the statement, wouldn't I have to move the whole if/else statement along with my declaration of string c inside the hanoi method? Otherwise the 'c' for comparing is not recognized inside that method.

Comment: Wow, what a simple and convenient answer. Thanks so much, sorry I am such a newbie to java, have only been doing it for about a month.

Answer (score 3):

Check this lines

```
if (c != lstep || c != lsteps){////}
```

This will work even if c is v or V. Say for 
If c = 'v' then c != 'V', so this 'if test' work for v or V. 
Change it to

```
if (c != lstep && c != lsteps){
```

Comment: Thacil Thank you. It's almost working except now when I type v or V, the output is incorrect. I edited my code above to show you. How do I get it to display the move list correctly?